# Are all modern astronauts at least passable phlebotomists?

Tags: crewed-spaceflight, health, astronaut-lifestyle, medical

[phlebotomists](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Phlebotomy) are (nearly always) highly skilled people who safely and relatively painlessly poke our veins with big needles, take blood samples, then ask us to "press here". The process is called a phlebotomy.

> the surgical opening or puncture of a vein in order to withdraw blood, to introduce a fluid, or (historically) when letting blood.

This requires training, *practice*, a medical background and will often require certification.

It's normally done in a medical setting so if there are any unexpected challenges they can be dealt with.

Phlebotomy has no doubt been common in spaceflight, medical research on the health effects of spaceflight has been central from its beginnings and is highly active today as extended missions are considered.

**Question:** Are all modern astronauts at least passable phlebotomists?

This would be a real challenge to do on yourself because of both geometry and human nature, every crew member will need at least one other crew member to be able to do this, so in crews of 2 or more there needs to be at least two passable phlebotomists.

Is it something that most or all astronauts are capable of doing, or are there just a few "designated drivers" in each crew?

Do astronauts phlebotomize each other during ground training for practice?

---

From the NASA.gov feature [NASA Researchers Develop a Technique to Predict Radiation Risk on International Space Station Missions](https://www.nasa.gov/feature/nasa-researchers-develop-a-technique-to-predict-radiation-risk-on-international-space):

[image: Japanese Aerospace Exploration Agency astronaut Akihiko Hoshide poses for a photo after undergoing a generic blood draw in the European Laboratory/Columbus Orbital Facility (COF)]

> Japanese Aerospace Exploration Agency astronaut Akihiko Hoshide poses for a photo after undergoing a generic blood draw in the European Laboratory/Columbus Orbital Facility (COF).

Comment: companion question: [First space phlebotomy? When was the first human veinous blood sample taken in space?](https://space.stackexchange.com/q/54710/12102)

Comment: Even if we don't count the recent billionaires who've gone to space as "astronauts", there have been space tourists who've visited the ISS and I'd be surprised if they trained in this.

Comment: It's not *that* difficult. Plenty of IV drug users inject themselves.

Comment: @PM2Ring it may *become easier* after a while, and of course plenty of other horrible and/or unconscionable things become "not that difficult" to do once someone is thoroughly addicted to opioids. I don't think it's a reasonable point.

Comment: I'd rather have a bottle in front of me than a fumbled phlebotomy.

Comment: It took me, as a pre-clinical medical student, about 2 minutes to learn how to take venous blood. I rather think it won’t take someone competent enough to be an astronaut any longer than it took me - taking venous blood from fit adults is easy.

Comment: @uhoh "IV drug users" include diabetics as well as crack heads. Of course the diabetics do get some training before they are let loose to look after themselves.

Comment: @alephzero No that's incorrect. IV = *intravenous*, the needle must puncture a vein under the skin, and for phlebotomy the needle is unusually large in diameter and called a cannula. On the other hand, diabetics [need to inject insulin **into the layer of fat directly under the skin, known as subcutaneous tissue, with a small needle or a device that looks like a pen**](https://www.medicalnewstoday.com/articles/316618#common-injection-sites) Apples and oranges.

Comment: @rhialto It's good to know, *thanks!* There may be some bias though, a pre-clinical medical student is likely someone who is less squeamish and more confident than average about puncturing another person. Granted, astronauts are probably less squeamish and more confident than average about things in general. :-)

Comment: @uhoh I personally know a nurse who periodically administers herself vitamin shots and stuff through IV. Like when she is tired she might take a one hour relaxation session with glucose and vitamin c or sth slowly dripping. It's not a big deal.

Comment: @ciamej I'd say that a nurse who periodically administers herself an IV and then falls asleep may be self-medicating with something more than vitamin C.

Comment: @uhoh ;) No, she's not falling asleep, she just relaxes.

Comment: @ciamej Yeah, I've seen a NP running glucose and I don't know what else into her because she wasn't feeling very good and was dehydrated.  I got the definite impression she set it up herself but I'm not certain.

Answer (score 57, accepted):

By my count, the OP asks three questions. I'll anecdotally answer two of them (*"Is it something that most or all astronauts are capable of doing, or are there just a few "designated drivers" in each crew?"* and *"Do astronauts phlebotomize each other during ground training for practice?"*).

I was the "backup" medical officer for [STS-109](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/STS-109) (the primary medical officer was a veterinarian!).

While training for said mission, I went to the medical clinic at the Johnson Space Center after hours for IV training. NASA had paid an unfortunate volunteer (someone who worked on site) to be my test dummy.

It took me about four pokes to succeed (those little catheters are hard to slide into the vein!). I felt bad for the stickee and did not enjoy the session. There was other medical-related training for me, but that was it as far as starting IV's.

Comment: "the primary medical officer was a veterinarian"... heh, I thought we were done with sending monkeys to space!  ;-) You discuss inserting an IV, i assume this means that drawing blood is only as hard as inserting an IV or easier, not harder?

Comment: @pcman Inserting an IV is harder than drawing blood, and drawing blood is harder than a subcutaneous injection.

Comment: I don't think it's intended to be 3 separate questions, but 3 alternative for who does the blood drawing on the ISS.

Comment: Out of curiosity, by "backup medical officer," do you mean that the mission had both a primary and backup medical officer on board when it flew or that only one medical officer was needed for the mission with a backup trained as an alternate in case the primary planned medical officer couldn't fly?

Comment: Have you ever self-administered an IV?  Is it reasonably feasible?

Comment: @RockPaperLz-MaskitorCasket I know a nurse who self-administers IV herself all the time.

Comment: @PcMan - the vets I know are really good at IVs, particularly the small animal (pets) ones. Try finding a vein on a cat and getting it in without completely pissing off the cat - you get one try...

Comment: @RockPaperLz-MaskitorCasket You didn't ask me, and I'm in infantry not space flight, but I have self-administered an IV while underway in a tracked vehicle bouncing up and down. So it is possible under adverse conditions. But my arm was bruised from armpit to elbow afterwards, as blood seeps from the vein under the skin during the procedure.

Comment: @reirab Not certain, but I'm pretty sure that the policy was to have at least two medically-trained crew on board (the thought being, "What if the primary medical officer gets incapacitated?"). Space flight planners are generally in love with redundancy any way they can get it. Organic Marble might know the answer to your question.

Comment: @dotancohen & ciamej  Thank you for your comments.  dotancohen, were you trained to self administer the IV, or just something you had to figure out when the situation arose?  (Also, what is a "tracked vehicle"?)

Comment: @RockPaperLz-MaskitorCasket "what is a "tracked vehicle"?" What would colloquially be called a "tank" by most civilians, though that term is used for a specific type of tracked vehicle by the military.

Comment: @RockPaperLz-MaskitorCasket I was not trained to self-administer, though I was trained as a combat medic so I was trained to administer to other people. Upon returning to my unit after medic training, the commander gave me the task of administering to myself. We were at the time traveling in [one of these](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IDF_Achzarit) which is a very bumpy ride.

Comment: "unfortunate volunteer" is a quite funny assembling of words :)

Comment: @dotancohen & nick012000 Thanks for your comments.  dotancohem, that *does* look like a bumpy ride. It's good to learn that the skill to administer an IV on others can be used on oneself.

Comment: @FélixGagnon-Grenier: another comical term for similar situations is "voluntold".

Comment: @RockPaperLz-MaskitorCasket A "tracked vehicle" is a vehicle that runs on tracks, not wheels.  Tanks, heavier armored personnel carriers and the like.  Not exactly known for having a smooth ride.

Comment: hah! that is a fine term @whatsisname, I shall reuse it :)

Answer (score -5):

**Question**: Are… astronauts… passable phlebotomists?”

**Answer:** No reason why they should be. Phlebotomy is passe. There is little potential need for venipuncture during spaceflight.

There are 2 reasons for needle access to veins:

**Diagnostic**. In hospitals, blood for diagnostics is usually collected by venipuncture using 5ml tubes. However, this volume is not required. Chemistry tests and hematologic tests can be performed on much smaller capillary samples from skin pricks.  https://pubmed.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/18070280 . This is standard practice in neonatal nurseries. Capillary samples are easily collected with no venipuncture skills. They can even be collected by the subject themselves. The ISS is equipped with a Bio-analyzer which requires only pinprick blood samples.https://www.asc-csa.gc.ca/eng/iss/bio-analyzer.asp

[image]

**Therapeutics** . Fluids and medications can be delivered through a number of non-oral routes:

1. Transcutanious (across intact skin), and sublingual (under the tongue).  This works well for fat soluble medications such as Fentanyl, Lorazepam and Nitroglycerin.
2. Subcutaneous. A short, fine needle is used to deposit medication in the fat layer just under the surface of the skin. Administration is simple and requires no training. Medicine is slowly absorbed into the capillaries, then carried by the circulatory system. Local anesthetics and Morphine can be administered by this route.
3. Intramuscular. Medication is injected into a muscle (usually the shoulder) using a longer needle than for subcutaneous. Minimal training is required. Most antibiotics can be administered intramuscularly.
4. Intravenous (directly into a vein). This is required for medications which require dilution to avoid tissue irritation. An example is Vancomycin. It is also useful for replacing large fluid volumes such as in trauma resuscitation.  Volume replacement is particularly urgent in hypovolemic shock (e.g.: massive blood loss) but IV access can be a significant problem due to peripheral vein collapse.
5. Fluid Replacement via Rectum (FRVR). This is an alternative to intravenous fluid replacement when IV access is not available. It is not routinely used in emergency departments due to availability of intraosseous (needle into bone marrow cavity) and peritoneal (tube into abdominal cavity) methods. Space medicine is a particularly good application for FRVR since it requires virtually no training and astronauts are on a perpetual low residue diet.

So phlebotomy is unlikely to be an essential procedure in space. It would be unreasonable to reject an otherwise qualified astronaut candidate for their poor phlebotomy skills.

Comment: The ISS has a fairly unusual #3 reason, *research*. Determining the effects of spaceflight on humans is a major long-term goal of the ISS project, and that involves sampling human bodily fluids at times.

Comment: @ceejayoz  What diagnostic test did you have in mind which cannot be performed on a capillary (finger poke) microsample?

Comment: Most of them? There's very little blood labwork that uses finger sticks; blood sugar is the most common. If you want a CBC or a metabolic panel, you're drawing blood from a vein.

Comment: @ceejayoz Yes, routine clinical practice is to use venipuncture to collect blood for adult laboratory studies. But it is not necessary. In neonatal ICU’s, capillary samples are often used to minimize iatrogenic anemia. Automated analyzers can perform hematology and chemistry studies on capillary samples. https://pubmed.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/18070280 .  Samples can be gathered in anti-coagulated capillary blood collection tubes https://www.ramsci.com/capillary-blood-collection-tubes . Astronauts could collect samples from themselves or each other.

Comment: NICUs have the specific problem of their patients sometimes being under a thousand grams. (My kids were 990 and 1000 grams.) Astronauts aren't in that scenario, and the better accuracy you can get from larger samples (which is the problem Theranos had, incidentally; you need enough blood to run the labs) is worthwhile.

Comment: This answer is just plain wrong. Astronauts take So. Many. Blood. Samples. We scheduled blood draws all the time for HRF.